# Writing roxygen documentation without saving .rd files?

Tags: r, roxygen2, rd

Is there a way to write `roxygen2` tags for a function without `devtools::document()` saving Rd files? I like the roxygen2-style for internal documentation (for other developers) of stuff that will never concern the end user. Right now, the "unnecessary" rd files end up shipping with the package.

Ideally, something like a `@noRd` tag:

```r
#' Add two numbers
#' @param x Numeric vector
#' @param y Numeric vector
#' @return Numeric vector
#' @noRd
add = function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There literally is a `@noRd` tag! I just didn't see it documented anywhere. Problem solved.